# Why do i have an empty file after sending stdout to it

Tags: bash, sed, filter, stdout, tr

Using bash i am executing following commands to filter information from a certificate

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null > cert.pem 
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -subject > commonName
tr "," "\n" < commonName | sed -nr '/CN/p' | tr -d ' /t' > commonName
```

The last command leaves the file "commonName" empty, i wonder why this is. 
If i instead append the file ">>" the desired filtered output is shown but unfiltered content remains.

## Leaves file empty

```
tr "," "\n" < commonName | sed -nr '/CN/p' | tr -d ' /t' > commonName
```

## Works but with undesired content

```
tr "," "\n" < commonName | sed -nr '/CN/p' | tr -d ' /t' >> commonName
```

Edit,
Might add that sending to a file with a new name works as intended. Changing "commonName" to "test" for example.

Thanks in advance!
/R

Comment: Think about it. How can you read and (over-)write to the same file _at the same time_?

Comment: Ahh there we go, still learning so in my world the limit is in the skies. :)

Comment: If you're learning, you may find [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) helpful. It automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2094) and other common issues

Comment: Thank you, bookmarked and very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit the file with other commands and sed in only one pipe (the way you do it). You need a temporary file:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null > cert.pem 
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -subject > commonName
tr "," "\n" < commonName | sed -nr '/CN/p' | tr -d ' /t' > /tmp/temp
mv /tmp/temp commonName
```

And a better way to achieve the whole script, without temporary file:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null > cert.pem 
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -subject |
    tr "," "\n" |
    grep -o 'CN .*' > commonName
```